# Set JAR name packaged inside a WAR

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

I created a `WAR` project and a `JAR` project, setted like dependency of the `WAR` the `JAR` project, I used the tag `<finalName>` in the `JAR` project pom file to set the file's name when the `WAR` is packaged.
I run the maven install and I check if all has the right name. The jar take the name of the project and not the name in the `<finalName>` tag. 
Why ? How set the name of the jar ? I use the `maven-war-plugin version 3.0.0`.

Expected result: AOL.war that contains webservices.jar

Actual result: AOL.war that contains JarProject-3.0.0.jar

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>WarProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>WarProject</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>b7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7-dep</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mate</groupId>
            <artifactId>captcha</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mate</groupId>
            <artifactId>sifw</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mate</groupId>
            <artifactId>sifw-devel</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mate</groupId>
            <artifactId>sifw-upload</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mate</groupId>
            <artifactId>sifw-velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>WarProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>WarProject</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!--sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory -->
        <finalName>AOL</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpContextName>WEBAOL</wtpContextName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src</source>
                                <source>src_mega</source>
                                <source>src_ws</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**/DocsServlet.class</packagingExcludes>
                    <packagingExcludes>META-INF/context.xml</packagingExcludes>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ProjectParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectParent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>JarProject</artifactId>
    <name>JarProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>webservices</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>delete-files</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>youbanking-ws</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlDirectory>wsdl/GestionePratica</wsdlDirectory>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            jaxws-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.12,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-clean-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.4.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>clean</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you provide a coy of your pom.xml file

Comment: Provide POM and make the question clear

Comment: Updated, @DhanasekaranDon the question can't be more clear than so: I want a AOL.war that contain a webservices.jar, but I obtain AOL.war and JarProject.jar

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the property finalName only changes the name of the created jar in the target directory, not in your local or a remote repository. Your war build will likely get your jar artifact from the local repository so finalName will not have any effect.

If you want to change the name of an artifact, change the coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version, classifier) in the pom before you build it.

Comment: I don't like this solution because I don't want change the project information, there is not a different way like use maven-war-pluging ? For example i set the war name in the maven-ear-plugin in the ear project pom

Comment: Actually, I don't know, but why do you want this? Why not just use the standard names? Changing names is confusing, and keeping conventions makes life easier.

Comment: Because If the project standard change and the output naming must be different I need a easy way to do this

Comment: I still do not see why the same jar should have _different_ names in your war and in the maven repository. What breaks if you just use the standard name "JarProject-3.0.0.jar" of the jar in your war? It seems like the natural thing to do.

Comment: The name in the war file can't be changed only if like to name inside the war file which I don't recommend cause you can change the namings inside the war but this means to change the naming convention for all jars See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/file-name-mapping.html but I strongly discourage that. As already pointed out by JFMeier follow the conventions it makes life easier....The finalName only changes the name in `target` directory...that's the way it is and can't be changed and will never be changed..

Comment: The jar take the name of the project and i don't want this. I want call it with a different name. Just because is a requirement. The filename mapping modify all files so is not the best way (like you said). There is a different way ?

Comment: If this is a requirement, you really should talk to the people and try to change the requirement. If you really want to install/deploy with a different name, you can use the `install:install-file` and/or `deploy:deploy-file` goals in your pom to deploy a file with an arbitrary name. But as I said: Not recommended, I would try to change the requirement.